# How to logout in django?

Tags: python, django

html code

```
{% if request.user %}
    <a href="{% url 'main:logout' %}">
        Выход
    </a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'main:registration' %}">
        Регистрация
    </a>
{% endif%}
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'main/index'
```

views.py

```
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL}, name='logout')
]
```

what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code (or tracebacks) in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: For anyone arriving here after migrating to Django 5.0 and facing a `405 Method Not Allowed` error, please note that as of this version, the `LogoutView` (from `django.contrib.auth.views`) no longer accepts `GET` requests (`POST` only). See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#features-removed-in-5-0) for more details and [here](https://codereviewdoctor.medium.com/3-awesome-django-4-1-changes-1-is-a-logout-deprecation-you-need-to-know-about-1d8166ccbdb2) for the explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using your custom logout view which doesn't take next_page parameter.
You should add it as parameter to your view and pass to django logout call, or just use **django.contrib.auth.logout**

e.g.   in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'next_page': settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL}, name='logout')
]
```

Comment: i did like you. But it shows me admin page. or I don't understand the logout function. I do my own web-site and did login now I want to log out from system.

Comment: you need to define LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL in your settings (in your example you defined LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL), or in urls.py instead of settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL, put "/main/index" (or whatever url you need).

Comment: it works. I logout from admin and in my website, but I don't understand one thing. It does not work. `{% if request.user %}
    <a href="{% url 'main:edit' %}">
        {{request.user}}
    </a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'main:login' %}">
        Вход
    </a>
{% endif%}    
`

Comment: You will always have user in request. In case that you are not logged in, it will be unauthenticated user.  You can go with: {% if user.is_authenticated %} <a href="{% url 'main:edit' %}"> {{request.user}} </a> {% else %} <a href="{% url 'main:login' %}"> Вход </a> {% endif%}

Comment: I highly recommend against this logout, take a look at Allauth's work/decision/references here: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#logout-account-logout  -- this is somethign serious to consider.

Comment: This is outdated.

Answer (score 20):

Django 2.0 it looks like it switched to a class based view

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), {'next_page': settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL}, name='logout'),
```

Comment: A nice addition.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me. I had to specifiy it like this: `url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page=reverse_lazy('login:login')), name='logout'),`

Answer (score 6):

For Django 2.2.x or higher,
if you are using `path` instead of `url`, then simply import `LogoutView` from `django.contrib.auth.views` in `urls.py`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
```

then add following path in `urlpatterns`,

```
path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
```

Note: You need to mention `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "my_url"` in `settings.py` for redirection after logout.

Answer (score 1):

import django logout first , just write `from django.contrib.auth import logout` at the top of your view file

Comment: i wrote it in views.py

Answer (score 0):

For me, the url 'logout' was being used elsewhere, despite Django loudly complaining if I removed the 'logout' url from urls.py (I am using Django 1.11). I have no idea why/where/how. My hacky working solution was to use a different url, 'signout':

```
    url(r'^signout/$', logout, {'next_page': settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL}, name='logout'),
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works on Django 4:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(template_name="template_to_redirect.html"), name="logout")
```