# How to implement logout in django in template?

Tags: python, html, django

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import os

# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if('loggedIn' in request.session):
        id = request.session['uid'];
        return render(request,"index.html",{'uid':id});
    else:
        return render(request,"index.html",{});
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index) ]
```

This is the first time I am doing a Django project. I was able to log in and now see the index page. Now I have a logout button as  Logout

So, what can I need to do to log out from the system.. Please I am not getting idea behind the same.. It will be great If, somebody helped me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069948/2282638

Comment: Django already has a built-in authentication system. Why are you implementing your own?

Comment: You might want to start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/

Comment: is there any way to implement in the way I have done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a custom view for logout and this will do your work. However, as others have rightly pointed out Django has builtin authentication system and this is basically redoing the same.

(urls.py)

```
url(r'^logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
```

(view.py)

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout

def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return render(request,"your logout page");
```

Comment: please import:-

from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout, authenticate

Comment: I changed    return render(request,"your logout page");      to     return  redirect('/')